# Configuring alerts on Alertmanager using Loki and Grafana Helm chart

Tags: grafana-loki, prometheus-alertmanager

I have installed Loki using the Grafana Helm chart version 5.6.2. I made changes to the Loki gateway (set a login and password) and connected it to an Azure storage.

Now, I want to set up an alert on Alertmanager, but I noticed that in the *values.yaml* file, it is configured by default to create PrometheusRules and ServiceMonitors.

However, even when I set the flag to true, nothing is being created. Prometheus and Alertmanager are deployed in a different namespace than Loki and Promtail. How can I add alerts to Alertmanager from Loki using these components through the Helm chart?